# gorose Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements

Tags: go

I use gorose for web project with golang ,code like

```
var tablecheckrequest = "checkrequest"

func (mysqldao *MysqlDao) GetAllCheckRulesByRequestId(id int) []map[string]interface{} {
    result, _ := mysqldao.connection.Table(tablecheckrequest).
    Where("requestid", "=", id).Get()
    return result
}
```

After a time I get this

> Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements (current value: 16382)

Why is this error happening?

Comment: Please edit this to use Markdown and be grammatically correct.  Also, do you get an error message?  And can you be clearer about what the specific issue is you want to solve?  And what have you tried so far to resolve this issue?

Comment: I suspect that the error does not happen on any of these lines. It would also be helpful if you told us which library you are using to connect to the db.

Answer (score 0):

I find out it finally!
There is the source code of gorose

```
func (dba *Database) Execute(args ...interface{}) (int64, error) {
//defer DB.Close()
lenArgs := len(args)
var sqlstring string
var vals []interface{}

sqlstring = args[0].(string)

if lenArgs > 1 {
    for k, v := range args {
        if k > 0 {
            vals = append(vals, v)
        }
    }
}
// 记录sqllog
//Connect.SqlLog = append(Connect.SqlLog, fmt.Sprintf(sqlstring, vals...))
dba.LastSql = fmt.Sprintf(sqlstring, vals...)
dba.SqlLogs = append(dba.SqlLogs, dba.LastSql)

var operType string = strings.ToLower(sqlstring[0:6])
if operType == "select" {
    return 0, errors.New("this method does not allow select operations, use Query")
}

if dba.trans == true {
    stmt, err := tx.Prepare(sqlstring)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return dba.parseExecute(stmt, operType, vals)
}

stmt, err := DB.Prepare(sqlstring)
if err != nil {
    return 0, err
}
return dba.parseExecute(stmt, operType, vals)
}
```

during this method a stmt has been create but never close!
to fix it we just need to add a defer stmt.close() durging method parseExecute() just like

```
func (dba *Database) parseExecute(stmt *sql.Stmt, operType string, vals []interface{}) (int64, error) {
defer stmt.Close()
var rowsAffected int64
var err error
result, errs := stmt.Exec(vals...)
if errs != nil {
    return 0, errs
}

switch operType {
case "insert":
    // get rows affected
    rowsAffected, err = result.RowsAffected()
    dba.RowsAffected = int(rowsAffected)
    // get last insert id
    rowsAffected, err = result.LastInsertId()
    dba.LastInsertId = int(rowsAffected)
case "update":
    rowsAffected, err = result.RowsAffected()
case "delete":
    rowsAffected, err = result.RowsAffected()
}

return rowsAffected, err
}
```